# How to make multiple choice using segmented control?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i have a segmented control with 4 different choice. basically, segmented control only accept for 1 choice, is that any possible to make user choice more than 1 choice? what setting/code do i need?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.
You need to create your own custom `UISegmentedControl` using `UIButton` and `UILabel`and so on.